# UILabel constraints in UITableViewCell change in landscape

Tags: ios, autolayout, uitableview

I've got a static `UITableView` in my storyboard that has a combination of system cells and custom cells. In order to make the custom cells look like the system cells, I've added a 15 point constraint from the front of the `UILabel` to the cell's contentView (to match the default separator inset of 15 points).

This strategy works well when the table view is portrait, but it looks like the constraints shrink when in landscape, as seen below:

Portrait:
[image: System cell alongside custom cell in portrait]

Landscape:
[image: System cell alongside custom cell in landscape]

You can see in the above image the "BUG REPORTING" section title, "Report a Bug" label (which is positioned by the system cell), and the line between the two cells are all 15 points away from the contentView's left side, but the "Logging" label is closer.

I've tried constraining the labels to the contentView with margins on and off, and the result is the same. The constraints for the custom labels even report different constant values when they're obviously the same shorter distance from the contentView's left side.

[image: Example of constraint information when constrained to margin]

[image: Example of constraint information when not constrained to margin]

Does anyone know what's going on?

Comment: In your first image, you have constant value of 7, can you please explain?

Comment: Sure. The margin is set to 8, so by constraining to the margin with a constant value of 7, I get the desired offset of 15 points.

Comment: It seems that, when you rotate device into landscape mode, the left padding of default cell's label increasing. It might be like when device is in portraint mode the left padding of textLable is 15pts and in landscape mode it is 20pts. You can create an outlet of leading space constraint of label and update its value in viewWillRotate: method. Also refer Vignesh answer.

Comment: Ah you're right, the inset is changing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try creating an `IBOutlet` for the label's leading constraint, and modifying it before the cell is displayed:

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, willDisplayCell cell: UITableViewCell, 
    forRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) {
        let leftInset = cell.separatorInset.left
        cell.labelLeadingConstraint.constant = leftInset - 8
        // - 8.0 accounts for constraint to margins in autolayout
}
```

Or, you could use size classes to set a different constraint for the Compact Height size class:

[image: Compact height size class]

Then, simply set the constraints' constants to 12 instead of 7 (or 20 instead of 15, if margins are not used).

Comment: This is the right idea (apart from the `awakeFromNib` option, since that is only called when the cell is first loaded from the Storyboard). I'll edit your answer to also include the method I used to solve it, and accept it.

Comment: Cool. Thanks for another way around.